# Use Git Hooks to detect a file change and push change to all branches (Bitbucket/Git)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, githooks

---**Updated**---

Is there a way to have global files amongst all branches such as using Git Hooks to detect a file change and push change to all branches?

For example:

1. We have 5 different branches that all have different commits in
   them.
2. They all contain a readme file.
3. They are all based off of the master branch.

We would like that when the readme file is changed anywhere it updates in all branches other branches.

I get the idea behind branches being separate, but it sucks to update 6 readmes.

From the comments it seems like this might be possible with git hooks...  So how would you create a hook to detect if the README file is changed from any branch and commit/push to all other branches?

Comment: You can merge the master branch back into your separate branch; e.g. `git merge master`. You can also use `git cherry-pick` to merge specific commits (and not all commits).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Right that what I've been doing - I was trying to avoid having to do the action over and over.  Also, sometimes someone update a readme in branch #1 and a different update in branch #4, which you don't know about if you are in branch #2 lol.  I wish there was if this file is updated ping all readmes to update.

Comment: This could be accomplished using a `post-commit` hook that cherry picks the commit to all other branches. You would have to be particular about your condition check, like when only the README file was changed to prevent propagating other changes.

Comment: Since your specific use case is the README file, you might also consider having a dedicated branch just for documentation, such as `gh-pages` and not even mess with it in other branches. I personally keep it in the project root `docs` folder and develop branch-specific documentation that doesn't merge into master until the rest of the branch is ready too. For most of my use cases, it makes sense to keep the documentation in sync with the code base, so it naturally follows the rebase master flow.

Comment: Are these long-lived branches that aren't designed to ever be merged back into master?

Comment: The branches will all eventually be merged into one.  Some contain certain features that get released months apart.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII So how would you create a hook to detect a README file change anywhere and commit/push to all other branches if a change is done anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

No. The idea behind the branches is their isolation.